# Having trouble increasing product quantity when multiple of the same product are added to cart

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.7

[Example Image Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Zds.jpg)

The image attachment: when i try to increase the quantity of the second item, the quantity of the first item increases to 2, instead of the quantity of the second item.

You can watch the video i uploaded here for better understanding: 
https://web.facebook.com/groups/1378481325739503/permalink/2373521109568848/

See views and template here: https://codeshare.io/GLp0Rg

MODEL:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=250)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product-detail", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')

VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size', 'size'),
    ('color', 'color'),
    ('package', 'package'),
    )

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title   

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    def get_total_discount_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.discount_price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() - self.get_total_discount_item_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.price:#self.item.discount_price:
            return self.get_total_item_price()#self.get_total_discount_item_price()
        #return self.get_total_item_price()
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def add_to_cart(request,slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item,slug=slug)
    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )

    item_var = [] #item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

        if len(item_var) > 0:
                for items in item_var:
                    order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                        variation__exact=items,
                    )


    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()

    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
        order_item.save()


    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        #check if the order item is in the order
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
        return redirect("order-summary")
```

TEMPLATE (Order Summary):

```
{% for order_item in object.items.all %}
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <a href="{% url 'remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus"></a>
        <input type="number" value="{{ order_item.quantity }}" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
    <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}">
        <input type="button" value="+" class="plus"></a>
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path
from core.views import (
    HomeView,
    ItemDetailView,
    OrderSummaryView,
    CheckoutView,
    add_to_cart,
    remove_from_cart,
    remove_single_item_from_cart
)

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(),     name='checkout'),
        path('order-summary/', OrderSummaryView.as_view(), name='order-summary'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
        path('add-to-cart/<slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
    path('remove-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
    path('remove-item-cart/<slug>/', remove_single_item_from_cart, name='remove-single-item-from-cart'),

]
```

Comment: Please also include your `models.py`.

Comment: I just updated my question. Thanks! @Pedram

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a foundemental problem with your models, which makes hard to accomplish what you want.

Basically, every `OrderItem` should belong to only **one variation**. So that you can easily keep track of the `quantity` of each variation.

So remove `Item` field from your `OrderItem` model and also make `variation` field a foreign-key field. With such schema, it is much more simpler to add or remove variations; just pass the variation `pk` to `add_to_cart` add do the process.

That was the basic idea; You also need to make other minor changes as well, but let me know if there is anything unclear or any further problem exists.

#### Edit

This is how your `OrderItem` and `Variation` model should look:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Also for your urls, I mean, `get_add_to_cart_url` and `get_remove_from_cart_url` method on `variation`, I think you should add another `kwarg` for the variation's `id` *or* just pass the variation's `id` (without).

Comment: Still not working, I don't think variation is the cause of this problem. If I add different item with variations, the quantity of each item works correctly. But if I add same item twice with different variations the item quantity only increases the first item. I think this has to do with the slug/ID of that same item. @Pedram

Comment: Yes I see; but **adding the same item with different variations** is exactly the _edge case_ for your database design. If you review database schemas for e-commerce, you will find that each variation should be added to `OrderItem` **separately**. That's a well known best practice.

Comment: Also, if you review your current database design, for each **item** (product), you are adding one `OrderItem`, so you can't handle the quantity of different variations correctly, because you have only **one** `quantity` field for all the different variations.

Comment: I think you are right, please can you rewrite the model code here so I can get a clear understanding @PEDRAM

Comment: Okay I will try it. Thanks @Pedram

Comment: Still do not work. I also tried adding a pk to the url, that do not work either.@Pedram

Comment: Please someone help me out. I think the issue is the button I have in the second row is still the same button i have in the first row. I've dynamically generated the rows of order items but i didn't dynamically assign the buttons to the correct order item quantity field. Can someone do this for me.

Comment: I found a solution for this problem, I use Django form to update the quantity of product with different variations.

Comment: @Hi3e Glad to hear that; Did you use `Variation` for each `order_item` or continue to use your initial model structure?

Comment: I continue to use my initial model structure.